# Passing multiple sessions_key to Facebook API

Tags: api, facebook

I'm current developing web-app that allows a user to associate their account with their Facebook account.

I have no trouble getting the users Facebook id/session_key and extended permissions.

What I am having trouble is caching the users data in a single call.

Their documentation for [User.getInfo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/) allows multiple uid's to be passed to the API and the basic info returned but I need additional details but it doesn't state mulltiple sessions_keys are allowed.

Is there an alternative or will I just have to take the multiple web request hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use the [Batch.run](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/batch.run/) for Facebook but it turns out you cannot pass commands that require different sessions keys.

So I have to take the multiple hits.